# Specify Dockerfile target in kubernetes deploymet.yml

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Say I have the following dockerfile:

```
# Build
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM node:12.18.4 AS build

WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir -p /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock .npmrc ./
RUN yarn install --no-progress --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .

# Release
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM node:12-alpine AS release

RUN \
addgroup -S -g 1001 example && \
adduser -S -G example -u 1001 example && \
mkdir /app && \
chown example:example /app

WORKDIR /app

USER example

COPY --chown=example:example --from=build /app .

CMD ["./node_modules/.bin/ts-node", "--transpile-only", "./bin/http.ts"]

# Worker
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM node:12-alpine AS worker

RUN \
addgroup -S -g 1001 example && \
adduser -S -G example -u 1001 example && \
mkdir /app && \
chown example:example /app

WORKDIR /app

USER example

COPY --chown=example:example --from=build /app .

CMD ["./node_modules/.bin/ts-node", "--transpile-only", "./bin/worker.ts"]
```

And the following `deployment.yml`:

```
...
...
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example
          image: example
    ...
    ...
```

How do I tell this deployment.yml which docker target I want it to build (release vs worker), and, therefore, spin up two k8 containers.

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't build images and has no idea what's in your Dockerfile.  You'd need to separately `docker build && docker push` each image.  I'd recommend doing this as two separate Dockerfiles and not trying to build two separate final images out of a single Dockerfile.

Comment: you have to build images yourself and push it to registry let's say there are two targets dev and prod. what you need to do is build two images with specific targets and push it to some registry, in the end specify that image url in your yml file

Comment: Did you followed [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) docs?  Do you need example?